# MediaPlayer stops playing when running within a service

Tags: android, media-player

I am using MediaPlayer to play a looping audio. It needs to play within a service. After several seconds it terminates. I've checked to see that my service is still running and it is. When I moved the code to an activity it worked fine and never stops. This has led me to believe that the problem has to do with threading. In the activity, MediaPlayer is running on the UI thread but in my service it runs in a thread of its own and one that is not bound to the UI thread. Perhaps this has something to do with it. I also declared my MediaPlayer object as a private static field but that doesn't help either.

Logcat only indicates that the "Media server died" with no further reason why.

If MediaPlayer needs to operate within the UI thread, how would I access that from within a service or any thread spawned by the service?

I am having this problem on Android 4.1. Here is approximately what the code looks like:

```
class PlaySound implements Runnable
{
  private static MediaPlayer mp;

  public void run()
  {
      this.mp = MediaPlayer.create(this.context, R.raw.sound);
      this.mp.setVolume(1, 1);
      this.mp.setLooping(true);
      this.mp.start();

      do
      {
        // Do something until told to stop thread.
      }
      while (true);
  }
}
```

I also moved the private field to my service and even removed the do...while so that the thread could terminate immediately after playing started but this didn't help either.

**EDIT:**

This appears to be a problem in Android 4.1. I tested my app on 2.3 on a device from the same manufacturer and it does not experience this problem. In fact, the 2.3 device had much less resources and a slower processor, so if anything it should have been terminated if resources were an issue.

Comment: I cannot see you calling `mp.prepare();` ?

Comment: create(): "Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given resource id. On success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be called again."

Comment: My bad, didn't notices that you are using `create()`. I think you should post some more code of your service and how actually you are starting it, so we can help.

Comment: hi AndroidDev.did you find any solutions?

Comment: No need to call mp.prepare(), when using create with resId. Just make sure you have sleep()-s  in your thread, giving mp time to play sound.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that i create a MediaPlayer inside a thread that is managed by the Service. Use Handler(getMainLooper()) to start and stop MediaPlayer.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
   mediaPlayer.start();
}
});

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
     mediaPlayer.stop();
}
}
, 30 * 1000);
```